# Passing a user object to a flask view using a decorator

Tags: python, flask

I want my authorization decorator to be able to pass a custom user object to the view that it decorates.

Currently, I am having the decorator set an attribute on flask.g to do this. Is this acceptable use of flask.g or is there a better way?

My code looks something like this:

```
def auth(f):
    @wraps(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        user = getUserObj(request.headers.get('user'), request.headers.get('pass'))
        flask.g.user = user
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

And then the view is:

```
@api.route('/info')
@auth
def info():
    flask.g.user # this contains my user object now
```

Comment: This is how I do it, and so far it hasn't seemed to have any problems.

Comment: Why not use the `flask.g` or `flask.request` context for this?